# How to retrieve a config variable inside a loop over the very same config yaml?

Tags: python, loops, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have two YAML files that I am using with Ansible to provision an ubuntu instance.
One YAML file contains all the configurations. The second one holds the ansible commands.
With one of these commands, I am trying to change the content of an .ini-file.

Ansible command:

```
- name: Set ini config
  ini_file:
    create: false
    path: ~/settings/general.cfg
    section: "{{ item.section }}"
    option: "{{ item.key }}"
    value: "{{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ vars.general.cfg }}"
```

Config file:

```
db:
  host: localhost
  port: 12345
  name: someName
  user: someUser
  password: somePassword
general:
  cfg:
    - section: A
      key: foo
      value: "connect://{{ db.host }}:{{ db.password }}@{{ db.host }}:{{ db.port }}"
    - section: A
      key: bar
      value: 123
```

Now the resulting .ini-file looks like this:

```
[A]
foo = "connect://{{ db.host }}:{{ db.password }}@{{ db.host }}:{{ db.port }}"
bar = 123
```

but I want the internal variables being replaced with the actual variables so it would look like:

```
[A]
foo = "connect://someHost:somePassword@localhost:12345"
bar = 123
```

Comment: How are you loading the yaml "config file" in your playbook ?

Comment: there is a general main folder with two subfolders. one is named task (containing the first file). one is named var (containing the config file). The config file works well for not nested variables. E.g. I can retrieve the contained section and key, but not the nested content of value.